# Copying an existing table data from read only database into read-write database MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases, for one I have only read access, and for the other i have read-write access. Let's call them A and B respectively.

There is a table in A that I need to copy(with its data and structure) into B. 
To copy its structure I have used 'LIKE' keyword, but it did not work out. So, i could not copy the data also.

Do you guys have any further suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we have an example of the SQL you use to copy using the `LIKE` keyword? To copy a table from one database to another, you'd do:   `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS backup_db.tableA;
    CREATE TABLE backup_db.tableA SELECT * FROM live_db.tableA;` or just use `mysqldump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a table from one database to another, you'd do:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS backup_db.table1; 
CREATE TABLE backup_db.table1 SELECT * FROM live_db.table1;
```

Or you could use `mysqldump`

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt dbname table1  > ~/export.sql
```

And to put it into the other database, you'd do:

```
mysql -u root -p dbname2 < ~/export.sql
```

Edit: Also, please note, if you had a master and slave setup, this would happen automatically. A slave is read-only while a master is read/write. Data from the master would automatically be copied to the slave, but you'd need two servers. Just for your information.

Comment: I didn't know we could do create table this way. Thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html). It will allow you to backup the table data/structure to file from server A and restore it on server B.

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```